# Snowflake External Functions using Azure Functions on Python not working

Tags: python, sql, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create an external function that can be used to upsert rows into MongoDB. I've created the function, tested it locally using Postman and after publishing. I've followed the documentation from https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-creating-azure-ui.html and at first, I used the javascript function they proposed to test and worked. However, when I run it it python I get an error. This is the code.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import pymongo
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient(os.environ['MongoDBConnString'])
db = cluster[f"{os.environ['MongoDB']}"]
collection = db[f"{os.environ['MongoDBCollection']}"]

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        collection.update_one(
                filter={
                    '_id':req_body['_id']
                },
                update={
                    '$set': {'segment_ids': req_body['segment_ids']}
                },
                upsert=True)
        return func.HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({"status_code": 200,
                "status_message": "Upsert Success",
                "Timestamp": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
                "_id": req_body['_id']}),
                status_code=200,
                mimetype="text/plain"
        )
```

The error states that `req_body` is referenced before being defined, failing at line `'_id':req_body['_id']`. In Snowflake I've created an external function called `mongoUpsert(body variant)` and I am parsing a simple query to test.

`select mongoUpsert(object_construct('_id', 'someuuid', 'segment_ids;, array_construct(1,2,3,4)))`

From what I can tell, the function is not receiving the `body` I'm parsing in Snowflake for some reason. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me? Can anyone also explain how Snowflake is sending the parameters (as body, params, headers) and is there a way to specify if I want to parse a body or params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started from scratch and stripped the layers one by one in Snowflake. So the Snowflake parameter is parsed to the body of the function but wrapped in an array which is then wrapped in another object called `'data'`. Furthermore, it expects the same schema as a response back. So here's below the template to use for Azure Functions when using Python.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Get body response from Snowflake
    req_body = req.get_json()['data'][0][1]

    ###### Do Something
    
    # Return Response
    message = {"Task": "Completed"}
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({'data': [[0, message]]}),
        status_code=200)
```

As an example, I've used a simple JSON object:

```
{
  "_id": "someuuid"
}
```

And created an external function in Snowflake called `testfunc(body variant)` and called it using `select testfunc(object_construct('_id', 'someuuid'))`.
If you would log the response (using `logging.info(req.get_json())`) it would print the following

```
{
  "data": 
  [
    [
      0,
      {
        "_id": "someuuid"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

So to get the clean input I fed in snowflake I have the line

```
req_body = req.get_json()['data'][0][1]
```

However, I kept getting errors on the response until I tried just echoing the input and noticed it returned it without the wrapping. The returned body needs to be a string (hence why using `json.dumps()`) but it also needs the wrapping. So to print it out, first define a message you want (it may be a calculation of the input or an acknowledgement), then wrap the message in `{'data': [[0, message]]}` and finally compile it as a string (`json.dumps()`)

Answer (score 2):

External functions send and receive data in a particular format. All the parameters are sent in the request body.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-data-format.html

You can checkout [snowflake-labs](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-external-functions-examples)
for external functions samples.

There is one specifically for [Azure Python functions](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfguide-external-functions-examples/tree/main/MicrosoftTranslatorAPI_Python) that calls the Translator API.